# How to make returntype of the class dynamic

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

We're using  PageObjects pattern for automation.
    I've function,

```
public className SelectTab(driver,path,className)throws Exception{
    driver.findelement(By.xpath("path")).click();
    return PageFactory.initElements(driver,className.class);
}
```

Return type should be the className that we're passing to SelectTab() because className is dynamic.

How I can do it?

Comment: Calling Function:
stStudentDashboardpage=stStudentPersonalArchives.VerifyParagraphInPersonalArchives(PSSSessionTitle);

Called Function:

 public STStudentDashboardPage VerifyPSSSavedInPersonalArchives(String PSSTitle)throws Exception{
  System.out.println("Title of paragraph submitted by student:"+PSSTitle);
    
  return PageFactory.initElements(_driver, STStudentDashboardPage.class);
 }

Comment: I neeed to call:
stStudentDashboardpage=stStudentPersonalArchives.VerifyParagraphInPersonalArchives(PSSSessionTitle,stStudentDashboardpage); 
 
Called Function should be like this:
 
 public ClassName VerifyPSSSavedInPersonalArchives(String PSSTitle,ClassName)throws Exception{
  System.out.println("Title of paragraph submitted by student:"+PSSTitle);
  
  return PageFactory.initElements(_driver, ClassName.class);
 }

Answer (score 1):

This ?

If your have classname as String

```
   public <T> T SelectTab(WebDriver  driver,String  path, T className) throws Exception{
        driver.findelement(By.xpath("path")).click();
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, className.class);
    }
```

and call SelectTab as

```
SelectTAB(driver,path,Class.forName(classNameString));// where classNameString is the value you are currently passing to SelectTab  with your code.
```

Or use something like

```
   public Object SelectTab(WebDriver  driver,String  path, String className) throws Exception{
        driver.findelement(By.xpath("path")).click();
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, Class.forName(className));
    }
```

Comment: I've to return something like.. return PageFactory.initElements(_driver, ClassName.class)

Comment: What's `obj` in this example?

Comment: NilsH - don't know What's obj

Comment: @RobMurphy so whats the problem? in above code you are returning `return PageFactory.initElements(driver, className.class);`

Comment: I got this error...  Multiple markers at this line
 - className cannot be resolved to a type
 - The method initElements(WebDriver, Class<className>) from the type PageFactory refers to the missing type

Comment: @RobMurphy are you sure you are suing 'T className' as parameter.. check the case sensetive varibale name

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29672/discussion-between-rob-murphy-and-rahul-maindargi)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Selenium handy, but perhaps this would work.

```
public <T> T SelectTab(driver,path, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception{
    driver.findelement(By.xpath("path")).click();
    return PageFactory.initElements(driver, clazz);
}
```

You may need to cast the result of `initElements` to type `T`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the Selenium [`PageFactory`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/PageFactory.html) you're using, `initElements` is generic, so you should be able to do:

```
public <T> T SelectTab(WebDriver driver, String path, Class<T> pageClass) {
    // selection logic
    return PageFactory.initElements(driver, pageClass);
}
```

Comment: I've to return something like..                          return PageFactory.initElements(_driver, ClassName.class)

Comment: I got this error... Multiple markers at this line - className cannot be resolved to a type - The method initElements(WebDriver, Class<className>) from the type PageFactory refers to the missing type